# Phantom <br> tag rendered by browsers prior to <table> tag

Tags: html, browser

The browser seems to be rendering a <br> tag prior to my <table>.  The entire page is supposed to be rendered in the same table, but there's an irritating whitespace being created by a <br> tag that isn't in the code.

The code looks like this, including when using View Source:

```
<body>
   <div class='container'>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="978px" style="border:2px solid blue;">
```

But the page has a fat space in the browser, and appears like this when I use "inspect element" in Chrome:

```
<body>
   <div class='container'>
      <br>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="978px" style="border:2px solid blue;">
```

I've pored over my CSS and my code and I can't figure it out.

Let me know if I need to be more specific somewhere.

Comment: So, when you inspect, you see the `<br>` tag? Or it just feels to you like there is a `<br>` element there you can't see?

Comment: Is there a live demo we can see, somewhere? Perhaps you could post a [representative demo on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show us the problem?

Comment: There is a visible, clear-as-day <br> tag when I inspect, all four characters.  I can even post photographic evidence.

Comment: Why should `<br>` automatically get added if it's not there in original?

Comment: A demo will be much more useful, as the glitch is not reproducible with the code you've posted.

Comment: Do you have some sort of JavaScript running on the page? The only way code would show up in the inspect but not in the source is if it was added to the DOM after the page loaded.

Comment: I've seen this happen when the html had some syntax errors.  As others have said, if we can see the actual page it would help.  Or at the very least post more of the code, we can only see the opening tags, not where the close.

Comment: This will be caused by you having a `<br>` inside the table but not inside a `<td>` or `<th>`. The `<br>` will be moved by the parser to be before the table by following the foster parenting algorithm. See http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/tree-construction.html#foster-parenting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't have any scripts on the page, the only thing I can think of is that it's being injected because your code [isn't valid](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://frk.ethierexcavatingnh.com/test_page/test_page_tickets.html). Try fixing the errors there and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Making the code valid fixed it, so thank you for the suggestion.  I'll go back and see what exactly I had going on that caused this particular problem, since I fixed it all at once, like a jerk...

Answer (score 2):

If there's really a `<br>` tag as shown through Chrome's Inspect Element, then I would check your Javascript as to my knowledge you can't insert DOM elements through CSS.  If you're positive that's not the issue, I'd try disabling all your browser plugins to eliminate the possibility of one of them doing it.

Edit:
It is invalid syntax, specifically

```
            <div>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="978px" style="border:2px solid blue;">
                <tr style='font-size:1px'><td width="200px">&nbsp;</td><td width="500px">&nbsp;</td><td width="200px">&nbsp;</td></tr>                        
                        <tr><td rowspan='2' class="logobox"><img src="http://www.frontrowking.com/images/FRK-LOGO.gif" alt="Front Row King Tickets" width="198" height="102" align="left" class="logo" /></td>
                            <td width='771px' height='70px' style='vertical-align:center; text-align:center;'>
                                Test Page Tickets
                                Keyword Text!
                                <div style='vertical-align:bottom;'>breadcrumbs &gt;&gt; breadcrumb</div>
                            </td></tr>
                        <tr><td colspan="2" align="center" style='vertical-align:bottom;'>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border-spacing='0' width="100%" style="border:none; max-height:34px; margin-top:8px;">
                                <tr class='navbar'>
                                    <td class="hov" width="18%"><div align="center"><a class="header-link">menu3</a></div></td> 
                                    <td class="hov" width="18%"><div align="center"><a class="header-link">menu</a></div></td> 
                                    <td class="hov" width="18%"><div align="center"><a class="header-link">menu</a></div></td>
                                    <td class="hov" width="30%"><div align="center"><input type='text' /><a class="header-link">search</a></div></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
            </div>
```

You closed the outer `div` before closing the `table`.  Moving the `</div>` after the `</table>` should do the trick.