# Why Does Chrome Insert Code Into My HTML Page?

Tags: html, css, html-table

[image]I have a page with two large tables, one positioned above the other:

http://files.sportsmogul.com/Encyclopedia/1907/BOS/index.html

In my editor (Dreamweaver CC 2015), there is no space between the tables.

But in Chrome, there is a unwanted gap of about 10 pixels (the blue space where the background shows through, between the top "navbar" and the rest of the page).

When you open 'Developer Tools' in Chrome, you see that Chrome has INSERTED a 'br' tag on-the-fly. (You can see the tag in the Developer Tools, but Chrome doesn't make any changes to my HTML file).

1. The first table closes on line 69.
2. The second table opens on line 71.
3. There is no code between these two tables (much less a 'BR').
4. However, Chrome inserts a 'BR' tag when displaying the file.

Why is Chrome doing this and how can I stop it?

Thanks!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html><head>
    <title>
    1907 Boston Americans
    </title>
    <link href="../../styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <style type="text/css">body {background-color: #606080; background-image: url(../../wallpaper.jpg)}</style>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
    function MM_jumpMenu(targ,selObj,restore)
    {
        eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'");
        if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <a name="top"></a>
    <table class="basic" width="HTML_TABLE_WIDTH" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" background="../../navbar0.jpg" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <tr><td width="70" valign="top" style="PADDING-LEFT: 10px; PADDING-TOP: 10px"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr><td height="27" valign="bottom"><b class="title">Year: </b></td></tr>
    <tr><td height="27" valign="bottom"><b class="title">Team: </b></td></tr>
    </table></td>
    <td style="PADDING-TOP: 7px"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr><td height="27" valign="top">
    <form name="form1" id="form1">
    <select name="menu1" class="navbar" onchange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
    <option value="../../1901/BOS/index.html">1901</option>
    <option value="../../1902/BOS/index.html">1902</option>
    <option value="../../1903/BOS/index.html">1903</option>
    <option value="../../1904/BOS/index.html">1904</option>
    <option value="../../1905/BOS/index.html">1905</option>
    <option value="../../1906/BOS/index.html">1906</option>
    <option value="../../1907/BOS/index.html" selected>1907</option>
    <option value="../../1908/BOS/index.html">1908</option>
    <option value="../../BOS/index.html">All Years</option>
    </select>
    <a href="../../1906/BOS/index.html">1906</a> | <a href="../../1908/BOS/index.html">1908</a>
    </form></td>
    <td><span title="Show All Years"><a href="../../BOS/index.html"><img src="../../history.jpg" alt="All Years" width="28" height="22" border="0"></a></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td height=27 valign="top">
    <form name="form2" id="form2">
    <select name="menu2" class="navbar" onchange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
    <option value="../../1907/BOS/index.html" selected>Boston Americans</option>
    <option value="../../1907/BSN/index.html">Boston Doves</option>
    <option value="../../1907/BRO/index.html">Brooklyn Superbas</option>
    <option value="../../1907/CHC/index.html">Chicago Cubs</option>
    <option value="../../1907/CHW/index.html">Chicago White Sox</option>
    <option value="../../1907/CIN/index.html">Cincinnati Reds</option>
    <option value="../../1907/CLE/index.html">Cleveland Naps</option>
    <option value="../../1907/DET/index.html">Detroit Tigers</option>
    <option value="../../1907/NYG/index.html">New York Giants</option>
    <option value="../../1907/NYY/index.html">New York Highlanders</option>
    <option value="../../1907/PHA/index.html">Philadelphia Athletics</option>
    <option value="../../1907/PHI/index.html">Philadelphia Phillies</option>
    <option value="../../1907/PIT/index.html">Pittsburgh Pirates</option>
    <option value="../../1907/SLB/index.html">St. Louis Browns</option>
    <option value="../../1907/STL/index.html">St. Louis Cardinals</option>
    <option value="../../1907/WSH/index.html">Washington Senators</option>
    <option value="../../1907/index.html">All Teams</option>
    </select></form></td>
    <td><span title="Show All Teams"><a href="../../1907/index.html"><img src="../../earth.jpg" alt="All Teams" width="28" height="22" border="0"></a></span></td>
    </tr>
    </table></td>
    <td width="200"><img src="../../navbar1.jpg" border="0" alt="Home" width="200" height="76"></td>
    <td width="198"><a href="leaders.html"><img src="../../navbar2g.jpg" border="0" alt="Leaders" width="198" height="76"></a></td>
    <td width="198"><a href="http://www.sportsmogul.com/baseballcd"><img src="../../navbar3.jpg" border="0" alt="Baseball Mogul" width="198" height="76"></a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- Chrome inserts a BREAK (BR) here. -->
    <table class="basic" width="HTML_TABLE_WIDTH" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <tr>
    <td style="PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; PADDING-LEFT: 10px" align=center valign=top><BR>
    <table class=table1 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width=310>
    <tr class=tabletitle><td colspan="3">
    <div align="center"><strong>1907 American League</strong></div></td></tr>
    <tr class=header0>
    <td width=195 class=ltl>Team</td>
    <td width=60 class=ltc>Record</td>
    <td width=55 class=ltc>GB</td></tr>
    <tr><td class=lml><a href="../../1907/DET/index.html">Detroit Tigers</a></td>
    <td class=lmc>92 - 58</td>
    <td class=lmc>&#8212;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td class=lml><a href="../../1907/PHA/index.html">Philadelphia Athletics</a></td>
    <td class=lmc>88 - 57</td>
    <td class=lmc>1.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td class=lml><a href="../../1907/CHW/index.html">Chicago White Sox</a></td>
    <td class=lmc>87 - 64</td>
    <td class=lmc>5.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td class=lml><a href="../../1907/CLE/index.html">Cleveland Naps</a></td>
    <td class=lmc>85 - 67</td>
    <td class=lmc>8.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td class=lml><a href="../../1907/NYY/index.html">New York Highlanders</a></td>
    <td class=lmc>70 - 78</td>
    <td class=lmc>21.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td class=lml><a href="../../1907/SLB/index.html">St. Louis Browns</a></td>
    <td class=lmc>69 - 83</td>
    <td class=lmc>24.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class=highlight2><td class=lml><B>Boston Americans</B></td>
    <td class=lmc><B>59 - 90</B></td>
    <td class=lmc>32.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td class=lml><a href="../../1907/WSH/index.html">Washington Senators</a></td>
    <td class=lmc>49 - 102</td>
    <td class=lmc>43.5</td>
    </tr>
    </table></td>
    <td style="PADDING-RIGHT: 10px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px" align=center valign=top><br>
    <table class="table1" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width=310>
    <tr class="tabletitle"><td>
    <div align="center"><strong>7th (AL)</strong></div>
    </td></tr>
    <tr class=header><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td class=lml>Runs Scored: 464</td></tr>
    <tr class="highlight"><td class="lml">Runs Allowed: 558</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="lml">Attendance: 436,777</td></tr>
    </table></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: it's a direct child of your `<body>`, after the first `<table>`. btw, don't use tables for layout purposes. Also, if you cannot find stuff, try searching for it with the search function.

Comment: Definitely a br tag. http://imgur.com/EPZPQMq

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rid of unwanted space between tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866134/how-to-get-rid-of-unwanted-space-between-tables)

Comment: Yes definitely a duplicate. Dreamweaver has a tendency to randomly add br tags when you move stuff around. Try using a programming text editor like sublime instead and see if you can find any br.

Comment: Add this css to your code: `td > br {display:none;}`. I wonder why you're not able to locate a br in your own code oO

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qKfKD.jpg

Comment: @gearsdigital Also I'd suggest that OP adds an ID or something to the table. Just in case there are any other br tags somewhere

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/72iam88qp/

Comment: Here you go. All br removed: http://pastebin.com/pD7U79Ab

Comment: The space between the first table tag containing the top "navbar" and the other table looks nice but that is besides the question and the point. As others have mentioned there is indeed a BR tag in between the tables as seen in the HTML source of the webpage. I would look at the HTML Dreamweaver is generating in the code view.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: OK. This is frustrating. You all seem to not have a lot of patience for me, possibly because I posted a question very similar to my previous question. But I did that because no one was able to answer the previous question, so I wanted to re-write it and re-title it in a way that better described the problem.

@Chris -- There is no <br> after the first table. You are about the 10th person to say this. "Try searching for stuff with the search function" seems more sarcastic than helpful. I know how to search. I have been using word processors and development environments for 30+ years.

Comment: @IsabelInc It is not "definitely a <br> tag". These short flippant answers are simply not helpful. Did you even look at the file? If you are so sure it's a <br> tag, please download the file. Open it in Notepad. And tell me what line number the offending <br> is on. (Despite claims by others to the contrary, I'm fairly confident that Notepad won't be adding or removing blank lines).

Comment: @gearsdigital I will try the CSS edit. Thanks. Removing all the <br> tags however is not an option. I have gone through the file and checked each <br> tag and every single one is there intentionally, and none of them are causing the gap that I asked about.

Comment: @Scott An image without any explanation is not helpful. :(

Comment: @j08691 I would have posted a minimal example but I have no idea where in the file the problem is coming from. For all I know there's an empty tag down at line 3000 that's causing a break to appear up near line 190.

Comment: Part of solving your problem involves troubleshooting, and part of troubleshooting requires you to start stripping code down until you get a minimal example. Often you'll find that this helps *you* find the problem without even posting a question to begin with.

Comment: @j08691 That's a good point but I already spent hours removing sections of the code to no avail. The gap appears in the full page but not in any smaller page that I was able to create. :(

Comment: Clay.. the image **shows exactly where the `<br>` tag is located**.

Comment: Wasn't trying to be flippant or disrespectful in any way. Was just trying to help. I did indeed check your file and I did find the br tag which is why I posted the image. I will go through the file again and let you know the line number. Hope that helps you. No one here is trying to be condescending. All of us are trying to give you constructive feedback but if that's not something you want then you'll find it hard trying to solve your problem.

Comment: @IsabelInc Thank you. I'm happy to receive constructive feedback. I think the problem is that folks on here don't realize that I've been working on this problem for more than a year and coding for more than 30 years -- and many other people have already tried to solve this problem -- so it's not going to be answered by just saying "yup that looks like a stray `<br>` tag".

It isn't a serious problem, but I keep coming back every few months hoping there's an angle that I'm missing. And my artist would kill me if he saw that there was a big empty gash across the middle of his work. ;)

Comment: For what it's worth... I used Chrome inspector to *delete that `<br>` tag* shown in the image above, and guess what?... the space vanished. If the the break tag isn't directly part of your mark up, then Dreamweaver may be adding it.... my personal opinion is DW rewrites **a lot** of stuff it isn't supposed to and it's a horrible, unreliable tool that was merely marketed well in the 90s. Zap "gremlins" (remove invisible characters) in a text editor..... not DW.

Comment: @ClayDreslough In response to your mention above. There is indeed a `<br>` tag between your navbar and the content below. If at least 10 people have said this, then they are probably right. I found it in 5 seconds which made me believe you are completely new to programming in general. I didn't mean to come across as snarky, but I see way too many low-effort posts on this site, and sometimes you just have to state the obvious. Anyway, perhaps this is a Dreamweaver issue? ...

Comment: @ClayDreslough ... Please take a look at these images [pic1](http://i.imgur.com/RCgVIOd.png) and [pic2](http://i.imgur.com/vL53aPq.png). As you can see, there *clearly* is a `br` tag there, and when I deleted it, the space was gone. Perhaps it's worth trying another editor? I personally use Notepad++ and/or Sublime.

Comment: @ClayDreslough did you see the 2 pictures I posted?

Comment: @Chris I did see the pictures you posted. :frustrated: We already know that Chrome inserts a <br> tag when it renders the page (see the 2nd answer below). The **file** doesn't have the `<br>` tag. As I have now said 4 times, including the original post, there is no `<br>` tag if you open the file in Notepad. This question is already rated at '-3' because no one is willing to look at the actual file in a text editor. Instead they just open it in their browser and assume I'm an idiot. :(

Comment: @Chris It's not a Dreamweaver issue. I mentioned in the original post that I opened it in Notepad and the `<br>` isn't there. I agree that if 10 people insist there's a `<br>` tag, they are probably right. But not in this case. You need to view the actual file (such as by downloading it and opening it in Notepad). Thanks.

Comment: @ClayDreslough, right, so then it must be that you have invalid html somewhere and that causes this error. As I said earlier, I would save myself the headache of getting the current table implementation working and replace tables with divs, where needed. If you still need help on this, I would post a new question and phrase the problem better.

Comment: Good point. However I've yet to find a convincing argument online that divs are better than tables, especially since these pages are indeed displaying tabular data. Can anyone point me to the one discussion or presentation that made them change their mind? I found CSS ZenGarden and the presentation at HotDesign (https://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/19cssintro.html) to be thoroughly unconvincing, at least partly because those pages don't resemble my content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My wife discovered at least a partial answer:

[Phantom <br> tag rendered by browsers prior to <table> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588638/phantom-br-tag-rendered-by-browsers-prior-to-table-tag)

Unfortunately, the solution to that question doesn't appear to solve my problem. I validated the code using the feature in Dreamweaver 2015 that submits it W3C service and it comes back with "No warnings or errors found".

Comment: I ran the check myself and I found 31 errors. [link](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sportsmogul.com%2FEncyclopedia%2F2007%2FBOS%2Findex.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). The code is hard to debug because there are no indentations, is that how it shows the code in Dreamweaver too? Also, many tags open in lowercase but close in uppercase (e.g `<td>` and `</TD>`) which also makes it a bit harder.

Comment: This is helpful. I actually found the same link last night. It appears that the Dreamweaver feature that allegedly submits the file to W3C is completely broken... and I'm probably dealing with a much larger problem than deleting one tag. I didn't write the original file and many of the errors (such as the non-breaking spaces) are essential to the page layout... :(

Comment: To be fair, there are many issues with your code, and I'm not saying this to be rude or anything. You are using tables for controlling the layout of the website and that's quite the no-no. It is possible that some missing tag or any other error may cause that problem. I actually don't even know how to begin debugging your code as I've never used tables for that purpose (as neither should you). By the way, the error occurs on all browsers I tested (chrome, ff and Edge).

Comment: I didn't design the page so I'm not offended, but I have about 20,000 similar files to maintain. Were tables *ever* recommended for layout (like 15 years ago)?

Comment: If I were you I'd save me the headache of searching what the error could be and just replace the tables that are used for layout purposes with divs. There seem to be only a handful of those, while the "data tables" are fine as they are. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is a `<br>` immediately after the navbar table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuQFH.png

Remove that and most of the space will go away. The leftover space is caused by the 'Home', 'Leaders', and 'created by' images in the navbar. The default alignment for inline elements such as those reserves some space underneath for letter [descenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender). You need to add a `vertical-align: top` style to each of those 3 images to remove the space. For example, the first image would look like:

```
<img src="../../navbar1.jpg" border="0" alt="Home" width="200" height="76" style="vertical-align: top">
```

So after removing that `<br>` and adding those styles to the three navbar images, it should look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv2Y3.png which I believe is the effect you were going for.

Also, just as a side note, Dreamweaver makes your code look absolutely atrocious and almost impossible to read. It makes finding these problems very difficult, which may be why nobody has really been able to help.

Comment: @IsabelInc No they didn't? They said they couldn't find the `<br>` tag.

Comment: Removing those doesn't eliminate the gap I'm asking about. Please edit the file yourself and open it in Chrome and see for yourself if you don't believe me. I appreciate different ideas but it's frustrating to me (and any other reader with the same problem) to see the suggestion stated as fact ("remove those and the spaces go away") when you haven't verified it.

Comment: @ClayDreslough It does remove the gap. Before: http://i.imgur.com/1sKeVlV.png After: http://i.imgur.com/kClMKtq.png

Comment: @person66 I was referring to the "blue" gap where the background shows through (see OP) -- this gap is caused by the first <br> tag that you see when you view the code in a browser, and I still don't know how to get rid of it. The other <br> tags are intentional and are producing the desired effects.

Comment: @ClayDreslough Oh I see. I've edited my answer with the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is in fact a <br> between your tables. Giving a line might not help because it could be different in dream weaver.

What I would suggest is, open this document and then once open, press the following at the same time. CTR + F (or CMD + F on a mac) A search box will pop up, then type <br> If you do this while at the top of the document it will bring you to the first break, otherwise go to the one nearest the top. That is the one causing issues. just delete it and problem solved!

Comment: FYI, I'm running Windows10. Was running Windows7 when I first discovered the problem. You are at least the 10th person to state confidently that there is a `<br>` tag between those two tables when there isn't one. :(

In Windows at least, if I download the file and use Search + Replace to eliminate all the `<br>` tags, the gap is still there.

If your results on a Mac are different, please let me know -- that might be some kind of clue. Thanks!

Comment: If it is something Dreamweaver is doing that's a whole different question and a title explaining that could much more easily get the answer you need. But I have downloaded it, and opened it in notepad and again, there is a <br> in the same exact spot. So if this does not exist in your original code, please post the original code from Dreamweaver because it is in fact part of the code on your website. and as a note, notepad does not include lines so again, I cannot give you a line, but it is without a doubt the first <br>

Answer (score 0):

Inside of every

```
<td colspan="3" style="PADDING-LEFT: 10px; PADDING-RIGHT: 10px">
```

are "br" tags. Search for this line and you will find them all, or look at what the poster suggesting using a search function has said, it is also sufficient.